# Order items based on an other field MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, functional-programming

I have a music theme for wordpress which has album listing page, albums are sorted `ASC` or `DESC`. I want the albums to be sorted based on another field which is a **post_modified**

As I am new in PHP and programming can not figure it out self. I am pasting the album.php file, anyone want to help me to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```
    <?php

    global $cs_node, $cs_theme_option, $counter_node;

    if ( !isset($cs_node->cs_album_per_page) || empty($cs_node->cs_album_per_page) ) { $cs_node->cs_album_per_page = -1; }

    $filter_category = '';

    $row_cat = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * from ".$wpdb->prefix."terms WHERE slug = '" . $cs_node->cs_album_cat ."'" );

            if ( isset($_GET['filter_category']) ) {$filter_category = $_GET['filter_category'];}

        else {

            if(isset($row_cat->slug)){

            $filter_category = $row_cat->slug;

            }

        }

         if ( empty($_GET['page_id_all']) ) $_GET['page_id_all'] = 1;

                $args = array(

                    'posts_per_page'            => "-1",

                    'post_type'                 => 'albums',

                    'post_status'               => 'publish',

                    'order'                     => 'ASC',

                );

            if(isset($filter_category) && $filter_category <> '' && $filter_category <> '0'){

                $event_category_array = array('album-category' => "$filter_category");

                $args = array_merge($args, $event_category_array);

            }

            $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

            $count_post = 0;

            $count_post = $custom_query->post_count;

?>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

       // jQuery('.icon-btn').tooltip();

    });

</script>



<div class="element_size_<?php echo $cs_node->album_element_size;?>">

 <div class="<?php if($cs_node->cs_album_view == 'Grid View'){ echo 'new-releases releases-four-coll';} else if($cs_node->cs_album_view == 'List View') { echo 'event albums-list';} else { echo 'new-releases';}?>">

 <?php if ($cs_node->cs_album_title <> '' || $cs_node->cs_album_filterable == "On") {?>

     <header class="cs-heading-title">

        <?php if ($cs_node->cs_album_title <> '') { ?><h2 class="cs-section-title cs-heading-color"><?php echo $cs_node->cs_album_title;?></h2>

        <?php if($cs_node->cs_album_filterable == "On" && $cs_node->cs_album_view == 'List View'){

                            $qrystr= "";

                            if ( isset($_GET['page_id']) ) $qrystr = "&page_id=".$_GET['page_id'];

                        ?>  

                        <div class="sortby">

                            <ul>

                                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php _e('All', 'Spikes');?></a></li>

                                <?php  if($cs_node->cs_album_cat <> ''  && $cs_node->cs_album_cat <> '0'){

                                    $categories = get_categories( array('child_of' => "$row_cat->term_id", 'taxonomy' => 'album-category', 'hide_empty' => 0) );

                                } else {

                                    $categories = get_categories( array('taxonomy' => 'album-category', 'hide_empty' => 0) );

                                }

                                foreach ($categories as $category) {?>

                                <li <?php if($category->slug==$filter_category){echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="?<?php echo $qrystr."&filter_category=".$category->slug?>"><?php echo $category->cat_name?></a></li>

                                <?php }?>

                            </ul>

                    </div>

                    <?php }?>



    </header>



 <?php 

    }}

 if($cs_node->cs_album_view == 'Grid View'){

    $args = array(

                'posts_per_page'            => "$cs_node->cs_album_per_page",

                'paged'                     => $_GET['page_id_all'],

                'post_type'                 => 'albums',

                'post_status'               => 'publish',

                'order'                     => 'DESC',

             );

            if(isset($filter_category) && $filter_category <> '' && $filter_category <> '0'){

                $event_category_array = array('album-category' => "$filter_category");

                $args = array_merge($args, $event_category_array);

            }

            $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if ( $custom_query->have_posts() <> "" ):

        $width = 228; 

        $height = 205;

        $counter_album = $counter_count = 0;

        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ): $custom_query->the_post();

        $cs_album = get_post_meta($post->ID, "cs_album", true);

        if ( $cs_album <> "" ) {

            $counter_album_tracks = 0;

            $album_track_mp3_url_audio = '';

            $cs_xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($cs_album);

                $album_release_date_db = $cs_xmlObject->album_release_date;

                $album_buynow = $cs_xmlObject->album_buynow;

        }





        $image_url = cs_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),$width,$height ); 

        if($image_url == ''){

            $noimg = 'no-img';

        }else{

            $noimg  ='';

        }

 ?>

        <article <?php post_class($noimg);?>>

            <figure>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>" alt=""></a>

                <figcaption>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><i class="fa fa-headphones fa-3x"></i></a>

                </figcaption>

            </figure>

            <div class="text webkit">



                <h2 class="cs-post-title cs-heading-color"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo substr(get_the_title(), 0, 33); if(strlen(get_the_title())>33) echo '...'; ?></a></h2>

                <div class="album_heading">

                <?php

                /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */

                $before_cat = '<div class="cs-event-catgories">';

                $categories_list = get_the_term_list ( get_the_id(), 'album-category', $before_cat, ', ', '</div>' );

                if ( $categories_list ){

                printf( __( '%1$s', 'Spikes'),$categories_list );

                }



                ?>



                <div class="social-area">

                    <div class="social-network">

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_amazon <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_amazon;?>" class="icon-btn icon1"></a><?php }?>

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_apple <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_apple;?>" class="icon-btn icon2"></a><?php }?>

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_groov <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_groov;?>" class="icon-btn icon3"></a><?php }?>

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_cloud <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_cloud;?>" class="icon-btn icon4"></a><?php }?>

                    </div>

                    <?php if($album_buynow <> ''){?><a href="<?php echo $album_buynow;?>" class="bay-btn uppercase"><?php if($cs_theme_option['trans_switcher'] == "on"){ _e('Buy Now','Spikes');}else{ echo $cs_theme_option['trans_album_buynow']; } ?></a><?php }?>

                </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </article>

        <?php endwhile; endif;

 } else if($cs_node->cs_album_view == 'home_view') {

     cs_cycleslider_script();

     ?>

        <div class="center">

            <a id="prev<?php echo $counter_node;?>" href="#" class="prev-btn bordercolr colr backcolrhover"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-1x"></i></a>

            <a id="next<?php echo $counter_node;?>" href="#" class="next-btn bordercolr colr backcolrhover"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-1x"></i></a>

        </div>

        <div class="cycle-slideshow"

        data-cycle-timeout=40000

        data-cycle-fx=carousel

        data-cycle-slides="article"

        data-cycle-carousel-fluid="false"

        data-allow-wrap="true"

            data-cycle-next="#next<?php echo $counter_node;?>"

            data-cycle-prev="#prev<?php echo $counter_node;?>">

    <?php    $args = array(

                'posts_per_page'            => "$cs_node->cs_album_per_page",

                'paged'                     => $_GET['page_id_all'],

                'post_type'                 => 'albums',

                'post_status'               => 'publish',

                'order'                     => 'ASC',

             );

            if(isset($filter_category) && $filter_category <> '' && $filter_category <> '0'){

                $event_category_array = array('album-category' => "$filter_category");

                $args = array_merge($args, $event_category_array);

            }

            $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if ( $custom_query->have_posts() <> "" ):

        $width = 228; 

        $height = 205;

        $counter_album = $counter_count = 0;

        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ): $custom_query->the_post();

        $cs_album = get_post_meta($post->ID, "cs_album", true);

        if ( $cs_album <> "" ) {

            $counter_album_tracks = 0;

            $album_track_mp3_url_audio = '';

            $cs_xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($cs_album);

                $album_release_date_db = $cs_xmlObject->album_release_date;

                $album_buynow = $cs_xmlObject->album_buynow;

        }

        $image_url = cs_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),$width,$height ); 

        if($image_url == ''){

            $noimg = 'no-img';

        }else{

            $noimg  ='';

        }

 ?>

        <article <?php post_class($noimg);?> style="position:relative;">

            <figure>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php if($image_url <> ''){?><img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>" alt=""><?php }?></a>

            </figure>

            <div class="text webkit">

                <h2 class="cs-post-title cs-heading-color"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo substr(get_the_title(), 0, 33); if(strlen(get_the_title())>33) echo '...'; ?></a></h2>

                <div class="album_heading">

                <?php

                /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */

                $before_cat = '<div class="cs-event-catgories">';

                $categories_list = get_the_term_list ( get_the_id(), 'album-category', $before_cat, ', ', '</div>' );

                if ( $categories_list ){

                printf( __( '%1$s', 'Spikes'),$categories_list );

                }



                ?>

                <div class="social-area">

                    <div class="social-network">

                          <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_amazon <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_amazon;?>" class="icon-btn icon1"></a><?php }?>

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_apple <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_apple;?>" class="icon-btn icon2"></a><?php }?>

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_groov <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_groov;?>" class="icon-btn icon3"></a><?php }?>

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_cloud <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_cloud;?>" class="icon-btn icon4"></a><?php }?>

                    </div>

                    <?php if($album_buynow <> ''){?><a href="<?php echo $album_buynow;?>" class="bay-btn uppercase"><?php if($cs_theme_option['trans_switcher'] == "on"){ _e('Buy Now','Spikes');}else{ echo $cs_theme_option['trans_album_buynow']; } ?></a><?php }?>

                </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </article>

        <?php endwhile; endif;?>

    </div>



 <?php } else {

    $args = array(

                'posts_per_page'            => "$cs_node->cs_album_per_page",

                'paged'                     => $_GET['page_id_all'],

                'post_type'                 => 'albums',

                'post_status'               => 'publish',

                'order'                     => 'ASC',

             );

            if(isset($filter_category) && $filter_category <> '' && $filter_category <> '0'){

                $event_category_array = array('album-category' => "$filter_category");

                $args = array_merge($args, $event_category_array);

            }

            $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ( $custom_query->have_posts() <> "" ):

        $width = 150; 

        $height = 150;

        $counter_album = $counter_count = 0;

        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ): $custom_query->the_post();

        $cs_album = get_post_meta($post->ID, "cs_album", true);

        if ( $cs_album <> "" ) {

            $counter_album_tracks = 0;

            $album_track_mp3_url_audio = '';

            $cs_xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($cs_album);

                $album_release_date_db = $cs_xmlObject->album_release_date;

                $album_buynow = $cs_xmlObject->album_buynow;

        }

        $image_url = cs_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),$width,$height ); 

        if($image_url == ''){

            $noimg = 'no-img';

        }else{

            $noimg  ='';

        }

     ?>

    <article <?php post_class($noimg);?>>

        <div class="event-inn">

            <figure><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>" alt=""></a><figcaption><i class="fa fa-headphones fa-3x"></i></figcaption></figure>

            <div class="text">

               <h2 class="cs-post-title cs-heading-color"><a class="colrhover" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo substr(get_the_title(), 0, 33); if(strlen(get_the_title())>33) echo '...'; ?></a></h2>

                <ul>

                    <?php if($album_release_date_db <> ''){?><li><span><?php if($cs_theme_option['trans_switcher'] == "on"){ _e('Released Date','Spikes');}else{ echo $cs_theme_option['trans_album_release_date']; } ?> :</span> <?php echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime($cs_xmlObject->album_release_date));?></li><?php }?>

                    <li><span><?php if($cs_theme_option['trans_switcher'] == "on"){ _e('Available on','Spikes');}else{ echo $cs_theme_option['trans_album_available']; } ?> :</span> 

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_amazon <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" class="icon-btn" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_amazon;?>"></a><?php }?>

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_apple <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" class="icon-btn icon-btn-2" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_apple;?>"></a><?php }?>

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_groov <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" class="icon-btn icon-btn-3" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_groov;?>"></a><?php }?>

                        <?php if($cs_xmlObject->album_buy_cloud <> ''){?><a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Itunes" class="icon-btn icon-btn-4" href="<?php echo $cs_xmlObject->album_buy_cloud;?>"></a><?php }?>

                    </li>

                </ul>

               <?php if($album_buynow <> ''){?> <a href="<?php echo $album_buynow;?>" class="bay-btn uppercase"><?php if($cs_theme_option['trans_switcher'] == "on"){ _e('Buy Now','Spikes');}else{ echo $cs_theme_option['trans_album_buynow']; } ?></a><?php }?>

                <a class="play-icon" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><i class="fa fa-play fa-2x"></i></a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </article>

<?php 

 endwhile; endif;

}?>

</div>

<?php 

    //<!-- Pagination -->

    if ($cs_node->cs_album_pagination == "Show Pagination" && $cs_node->cs_album_view <> 'home_view' ) {

        $qrystr = '';

        if(cs_pagination($count_post, $cs_node->cs_album_per_page, $qrystr) <> ''){

            // pagination start

            if ( $cs_node->cs_album_pagination == "Show Pagination" and $cs_node->cs_album_per_page > 0 ) {

                    if ( isset($_GET['page_id']) ) $qrystr = "&page_id=".$_GET['page_id'];

                    if ( isset($_GET['filter_category']) ) $qrystr .= "&filter_category=".$_GET['filter_category'];

                    echo cs_pagination($count_post, $cs_node->cs_album_per_page, $qrystr);

                }

     // pagination end

        }

    }

    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: All of the code used for ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While preparing arguments for WP_Query, you can additionally give field name for sort order.I have modified your $args, its should look like below:

```
$args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'            => "$cs_node->cs_album_per_page",
                    'paged'                     => $_GET['page_id_all'],
                    'post_type'                 => 'albums',
                    'post_status'               => 'publish',
                    'orderby'                   => 'modified'
                    'order'                     => 'DESC',
                 );
```

Notice here that I have added new element '**orderby**' in your array, you can know more about WP_Query on https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

it should solve your problem now